# Golang copy from *os.file without hanging on waiting for EOF

Tags: shell, go, ssh, pty

I'm trying to copy from a file in go using `io.Copy`, which waits for an EOF before actually copying the bytes out of its internal buffer, correct? In my use case (PTY/SSH session) the EOF only comes when the session completes, which means I am flying blind the whole time until the session decides that its over.

I've tried to use CopyN with 1 byte at a time which does work, but if I try to wait for a certain bit of text to come up and I copy one past what has been pushed to the file the code will hang and I lose the session. Is there a function to just "read whats there" and then stop, or a different marker (like EOF) that can tell copy to stop for now?

I have also tried to read the contents of the file that ptyI.pty points to but it always returns 0 bytes so I cant check for updates there

Here is the code that handles it as of right now:

```
type PtyInterface struct {
    pty          *os.File
    buf          *bytes.Buffer
}

func (ptyI *PtyInterface) PrivCmd(cmdStr string) (string, error) {

    // Copy the command provided into the STDIN of the bash shell we opened with
    // the earlier PtyInterface
    _, _ = io.Copy(ptyI.pty, strings.NewReader(string("somecommand")))

    // Assuming everything has gone well, we wait for the prompt to appear

    // We do this by running through individual bytes until the prompt is
    // fully printed (otherwise we might try to send in the answer at the wrong time)
    for !strings.HasSuffix(ptyI.buf.String(), "Prompt question? ") {
        _, _ = io.CopyN(ptyI.buf, ptyI.pty, 1)
    }

    // Once we hit the prompt we throw the answer into STDIN along with a newline
    // and the bash shell should accept this and begin executing the command.
    _, _ = io.Copy(ptyI.pty, strings.NewReader(string("answer\n")))

    // If we dont throw an exit in there then the PTY will never receive an EOF marker and we'll
    // hang on the next copy
    _, _ = io.Copy(ptyI.pty, strings.NewReader(string("exit\n")))

    // Now this copy will wait for an EOF
    _, _ = io.Copy(ptyI.buf, ptyI.pty)

    //Debug info to be printed after
    fmt.Println("\nBytes written to buffer (newone): \n" + ptyI.buf.String())

    return ptyI.buf.String(), nil
}
```

Comment: `io.Copy` doesn't wait for an EOF before it *starts* copying. It waits for an EOF to know that it's *done* copying.

Comment: If the output is line buffered, you could just use a scanner. Have you tried just calling `Read` directly?

Comment: @Adrian But nothing appears in the buffers outside the function before it knows that its finished reading the file

Comment: @JimB I have tried that using that, and I can, but it will still hang if there is nothing to read. My goal is that if there is nothing to read it will just return an empty string

Comment: @XanderMay; that's not how reading form a connection works. If there's nothing to read, it blocks until EOF.

Comment: @JimB Is there any way to see if there is something to read before trying to read it so that I can prevent a block? Or should I throw the reader into a concurrent thing and have it emit a notif whenever it gets something to read (this seems way too complicated but if its the only way...)

Comment: @XanderMay: no, you can't see if there's anything to read, you block until the Read method returns. Concurrency in Go is quite simple, if you have other things to do while you read from the connection, handle the reading in a goroutine.

Comment: instead of using Copy, implement custom byte copy function with terminator based (i.e., new line) or timeout based logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of `io.Copy` as a convenance function for bulk copying or streams, not the right tool for request/response patterns.

Just accumulate bytes into messages by checking if it matches the message on every byte. Use the Read method directly.

```
func Expect(message string, r io.Reader) (resp string, err error) {
    b := []byte{0} // 1 byte buffer
    var n int

    for err == nil {
        n, err = r.Read(b)
        if n == 0 {
            continue
        }
        resp += string(b[0])
        if strings.HasSuffix(resp, message) {
            return resp, err
        }
    }

    return resp, err
}
```

In your example you could use this like:

```
resp, err := Expect("Prompt question? ", ptyI.pty)
```

Here's a demonstration of it in action with a simulated connection io.Reader: [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8UJB5oR2mWV).